# PGP Encrypted Marketing Cloud e-mails

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption, pgp

Can the Marketing Cloud send PGP encrypted e-mails?

This is a fairly short question but I couldn't find anything precise on the topic, either in documentation or via Google. The documentation only mentions "... digitally sign messages ..." on the [Key Management page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_key_management.htm&type=5).

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2):

After consultation with a very senior Solution Engineer I found my answer, which I will provide with two parts to the answer for better understanding and documentation for future searches around this:

1. No, **PGP encryption of e-mails doesn't work** (or likely any other means). It's kind of plausible because this would have a massive impact on the sending infrastructure. It's likely to rare a use case to bother with development at this sort of scale. Totally understandable to be honest ...
2. **"Digitally Sign Messages"** in the documentation refers to [S/MIME, which allows to sign messages with a digital certificate](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336888&type=1&mode=1) that ensures the **sender is correct and the message is not tampered with**. From what I understand this is basically another layer on top of DMARC for increased trust.

I was warned though, that the **S/MIME feature is a very old one and there is no guaranteee** that it still has full support on all the various send methods now available.